# Mediaelementplayer not working in mobile phones

Tags: javascript, html, css, mediaelement.js

I have this code [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Wil1478so596/pen/PooWVON) to modify a working mp3 player, it works fine everywhere, even in small windows in desktop. but the buttons wouldn't show up in mobile phones. I figured out it was because of the Mediaelementplayer  that I'm using, but could not solve the problem. Thanks If you would fork that pen and show me a better way to do it.

```js
var audio = {    
    init: function() {        
    var $that = this;        
        $(function() {            
            $that.components.media();        
        });    
    },
    components: {        
        media: function(target) {            
            var media = $('audio.fc-media', (target !== undefined) ? target : 'body');            
            if (media.length) {                
                media.mediaelementplayer({                    
                    audioHeight: 40,
                    features : ['playpause', 'current', 'duration', 'progress', 'volume', 'tracks', 'fullscreen'],
                    alwaysShowControls      : true,
                    timeAndDurationSeparator: '<span></span>',
                    iPadUseNativeControls: true,
                    iPhoneUseNativeControls: true,
                    AndroidUseNativeControls: true                
                });            
            }        
        },
            
    },
};
audio.init();
```

```css
*:focus{
    outline: none;
}
html {
    background: #f2f2f2;
 height:100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Raleway",sans-serif;
 height:100%;
}
h1 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 33px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 10%;
}
h3 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 0 10%;
}
.container {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 750px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.music-player {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 570px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    background: transparent linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(10,11,31,0.9) 50%,rgb(10,11,31) 70%) repeat scroll 0 0;
    box-shadow: 1px 10px 20px 5px #222;
}
.series-name
{ font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 font-size:39px;
 text-align:center;
 width:100%;
 margin: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
 color:#ccc;
 width:400px;
 background:#090b1f;
 box-shadow: 1px 10px 20px 5px #222;
 border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;

` 
}
.cover {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 66%;
 

}
.cover img {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8%;
    left: 14%;
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
  
}
.titre {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.lecteur {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.mejs__button>button:focus {
    outline: 0px dotted #999;
}
.mejs__container {
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
    min-width: auto !important;
}
.mejs__controls {
    padding: 0 10%;
    background: transparent !important;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.mejs__controls div {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.mejs__controls .mejs__playpause-button {
    position: absolute !important;
    right: 8%;
    bottom: 95%;
    width: 40px;
}
.mejs__controls .mejs__playpause-button button {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #5bbb95;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.mejs__controls .mejs__play button:before{
    content:"\f04b";
}
.mejs__controls .mejs__pause button:before{
    content:"\f04c";

}
.mejs__controls .mejs__volume-button button {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #5bbb95;
    background: transparent;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.mejs__controls .mejs__mute button:before {
    content: "\f028";
}
.mejs__controls .mejs__unmute button:before {
    content: "\f026";
}
.mejs__controls .mejs__time {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 7%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    color: #fff;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    min-width: 100%;
}
.mejs__controls .mejs__time span {
    font-size: 15px;
}
.mejs__controls span.mejs__duration {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    color: #ccc;
}
.mejs__controls span.mejs__currenttime {
    font-weight: 700;
    float: left;
}
.mejs__controls .mejs__time-rail {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.mejs__controls .mejs__time-rail span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.mejs__controls .mejs__time-rail .mejs__time-loaded {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}
.mejs__controls .mejs__time-rail .mejs__time-float {
    display: none;
    top: -40px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 0;
}
.mejs__controls .mejs__time-rail .mejs__time-float-current {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 26px;
    color: #100d28;
}
.mejs__controls .mejs__time-rail .mejs__time-float-corner {
    top: auto;
    bottom: -9px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 6px solid #fff;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
}
.mejs__controls .mejs__time-rail .mejs__time-current {
    background: #5BBB95 none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
.mejs__controls .mejs__time-handle {
    display: none;
}
.mejs__controls .mejs__volume-button {
    position: relative;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 70px;
    right: 25%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
.mejs__controls .mejs__horizontal-volume-slider {
    display: block;
    position: absolute !important;
    position: relative;
    top: 70px;
    right: 10%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 4px;
    margin-top: 18px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    line-height: 11px;
}
.mejs__controls .mejs__horizontal-volume-slider .mejs__horizontal-volume-total,
.mejs__controls .mejs__horizontal-volume-slider .mejs__horizontal-volume-current {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
.mejs__controls .mejs__horizontal-volume-slider .mejs__horizontal-volume-current {
    background: #fff;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.container {
 height:400px;
}
.music-player {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
 height:100%;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    background: transparent linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(10,11,31,0.9) 50%,rgb(10,11,31) 70%) repeat scroll 0 0;
    box-shadow: 1px 10px 20px 5px #222;
}
.series-name
{ display:none;
}

}
```

```html
<html><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Sermon</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mediaelement/4.2.7/mediaelementplayer.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mediaelement/4.2.7/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://readamind.com/music1/music1/index.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="contain">
        <div class="container">
           <div class="series-name">Album</div>
            <div class="music-player">
                <div class="cover">
                    <img src="http://readamind.com/music1/music1/data/frame.png" alt="">   
                </div>
                <div class="titre">
                    <h3>Artist Name</h3>
                    <h1>Song Title</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="lecteur">
                    <audio style="width: 100%;" class="fc-media">
                        <source src="http://readamind.com/music1/music1/data/acousticbreeze.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
                    </audio>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

   
    <script src="http://readamind.com/music1/music1/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
<!--Test-->
```